# Searching through lists with Scheme (DrRacket)

Tags: list, search, scheme, racket, member

So here's my code:

```
(define *graph* (read(open-input-file "starbucks4.sxml")))

(define get-artifacts
  (lambda (l)
   (member (list 'opm:artifact) l)))
```

When I type `get-artifacts(*graph*)` I get an error saying `procedure application: expected procedure, given:...(the whole of my file contents)`

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks guys :)

PS: I'm really new to Scheme so it's probably some stupid syntax I'm forgetting!

Comment: Do you mean (get-artifacts \*graph\*)?

Comment: Thanks Paul, I think this is the problem. I'm having other issues now, but I'll try and sort them out myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for calling a function in scheme is `(function-name arguments)`, not `function-name(arguments)`.

When you write `get-artifacts(*graph*)`, racket first evaluates `get-artifacts` which evaluates to itself.

Then it tries to evaluate `(*graph*)`, which it takes to be a function call with no arguments. That does not work because `*graph*` is a list and not a function. So you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to your other question; it looks like you're in search of sxpath, here.